# Is there a Jenkins Plugin that allows you to manually manipulate the build queue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm looking for a Jenkins plugin that allows you to manually manipulate the build queue. The use cases are:

- We have a number of build jobs that run and at certain points in our development cycle we would like to have some builds to have a higher priority.
- When a build fails we want get it fixed as quickly as possible and therefore move it to the top of the build queue. (We don't want to cancel all the other builds in the queue)

While searching for this I have found the following plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin but do not believe it will meet our needs since I do not know in advance which builds I want to give priority to.

Really I'm looking for a plugin that gives you the functionality to click and drag builds in the queue, like on TeamCity.

Comment: The priority sorter plugin looks like the best shot so far. I have similar problem and I will try it out. You can take a better look at the Priority Strategies section on the plugin page. It supports strategy like parameter and job health, you might be able to get what you want by playing with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Accelerated Build Now](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Accelerated+Build+Now+Plugin) plugin does this job. It will even cancel running jobs if no processor on any node is free.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I haven't found practical plugins for this general problem.
Instead, I have a setup where there is a (small) dedicated node that is normally sitting offline and unused.
By playing with ad-hoc node labels that target the particular job I want to run, I can make that job jump to this node when I want it to jump the queue. The key is in preparing the jobs templates to include a job-specific label, for instance, e.g.:

```
# \/ normal requirements \/      \/ manual overridde \/
(linux && !offline && gradle) || <jobname>
```

where <jobname> is the job-specific label that is activated on the standby  node, as needed. YMMV.